Creditmax (PaymentSession initialized: ERROR)
I'm trying to set up a simple payment checkout using the Credimax/Mastercard payment gateway, but I keep running into an error. The error message I'm receiving is:

I'm not sure why this is happening. Below is the code I'm working with. I'm using createSession.php to create a session and then attempting to process the payment through processPayment.php. Here is my payment.html file:
payment.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Payment Page</title>  <script src="https://credimax.gateway.mastercard.com/form/version/100/merchant/TESTE12345/session.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Payment Page</h1>
  <div>Please enter your payment details:</div>
  <h3>Credit Card</h3>
  <div>Card Number:
    <input type="text" id="card-number" class="input-field" autocomplete="off" readonly>
  </div>
  <div>
    Expiry Month:
    <input type="text" id="expiry-month" class="input-field" autocomplete="off" readonly>
  </div>
  <div>
    Expiry Year:
    <input type="text" id="expiry-year" class="input-field" autocomplete="off" readonly>
  </div>
  <div>
    Security Code:
    <input type="text" id="security-code" class="input-field" autocomplete="off" readonly>
  </div>
  <div>
    Cardholder Name:
    <input type="text" id="cardholder-name" class="input-field" autocomplete="off" readonly>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="payButton" onclick="pay();">
      Pay Now
    </button>
  </div>
  <script>
    let sessionId;
    let paymentSessionConfigured = false;

    
// Fetch session ID from the server
    fetch('createSession.php')
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.json(); 
// Parse response as JSON
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log('Data received from createSession.php:', data);

        if (data.sessionId) {
          sessionId = data.sessionId;
          console.log('Session ID:', sessionId, 'Type:', typeof sessionId);

          
// Ensure sessionId is a string
          if (typeof sessionId !== 'string') {
            throw new Error('Session ID is not a string');
          }

          
// Generate a unique order ID
          const orderId = 'ORDER' + new Date().getTime();
          console.log('Order ID:', orderId);

          
// Configure the payment session
          PaymentSession.configure({
            session: { id: sessionId },
                        fields: {
              card: {
                number: "#card-number",
                securityCode: "#security-code",
                expiryMonth: "#expiry-month",
                expiryYear: "#expiry-year",
                nameOnCard: "#cardholder-name"
              },
            },
            frameEmbeddingMitigation: ['javascript'],
            callbacks: {
              initialized: function (response) {
                console.log('PaymentSession initialized:', response);
                paymentSessionConfigured = true;
              },
              formSessionUpdate: function (response) {
                console.log('formSessionUpdate response:', response);
                if (response.status === 'OK') {
                  
// Session updated successfully
                  const updatedSessionId = response.session.id;
                  console.log('Updated Session ID:', updatedSessionId, 'Type:', typeof updatedSessionId);

                  
// Ensure updatedSessionId is a string
                  if (typeof updatedSessionId !== 'string') {
                    alert('Invalid session ID received. Please try again.');
                    return;
                  }

                  
// Process payment with the updated session ID and order ID
                  processPayment(updatedSessionId, orderId);
                } else {
                  
// Handle errors
                  console.error('Session update failed:', response);
                  alert('Payment failed. Please check your details and try again.');
                }
              }
            },
          });

        } else {
          throw new Error('Session ID not found in response');
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching session ID:', error);
        alert('Failed to initialize payment session. Please try again later.');
      });

    function pay() {
      console.log('PaymentSession:', PaymentSession);
      console.log('Session ID at pay():', sessionId);

      
// Ensure the session is initialized
      if (!paymentSessionConfigured) {
        alert('Payment session is not ready. Please wait a moment and try again.');
        return;
      }

      
// Update the session with the card details from the form
      PaymentSession.updateSessionFromForm('card');
    }

    function processPayment(updatedSessionId, orderId) {
      console.log('Processing payment with session ID:', updatedSessionId, 'Type:', typeof updatedSessionId);

      
// Ensure updatedSessionId is a string
      if (typeof updatedSessionId !== 'string') {
        alert('Invalid session ID. Please try again.');
        return;
      }

      
// Send the session ID and order ID to the server to process the payment
      fetch('processPayment.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: 'sessionId=' + encodeURIComponent(updatedSessionId) + '&orderId=' + encodeURIComponent(orderId),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          if (data.status === 'success') {
            alert(data.message);
            
// Redirect or update the UI as needed
          } else {
            alert(data.message);
            console.error('Payment Error:', data.data);
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error processing payment:', error);
          alert('An error occurred while processing your payment. Please try again.');
        });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>

createSession.php
<?php
// Enable error reporting (remove in production)
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Use consistent API version
$apiVersion = "100"; 
$merchantId = "TESTE123456"; 
$password = "myapipassword3432489723";  

$apiUrl = "https://credimax.gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/$apiVersion/merchant/$merchantId/session";

// Initialize cURL
$ch = curl_init($apiUrl);

// Set cURL options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "merchant.$merchantId:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Accept: application/json'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{}'); 
// Send an empty JSON object

// Make the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Log the response for debugging
error_log("Response from MPGS API: " . $response);

// Check for cURL errors
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
  $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  http_response_code(500);
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode(array('error' => 'cURL error: ' . $error_msg));
  exit;
}

// Get HTTP response code
$http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

// Close cURL
curl_close($ch);

// Decode the response
$sessionResponse = json_decode($response, true);

// Check for JSON decode errors
if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
  http_response_code(500);
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode(array(
    'error' => 'Invalid JSON response',
    'json_error' => json_last_error_msg(),
    'raw_response' => $response
  ));
  exit;
}

// Check if session ID is present
if (isset($sessionResponse['session']['id'])) {
  
// Get the session ID
  $sessionId = $sessionResponse['session']['id'];

  
// Return the session ID in JSON format
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode(['sessionId' => $sessionId]);
} else {
  
// Handle error
  http_response_code($http_status);
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode(array(
    'error' => 'Failed to retrieve session ID',
    'http_status' => $http_status,
    'response' => $sessionResponse,
    'raw_response' => $response
  ));
}
?>

processPayment.php
<?php
// Enable error reporting (remove in production)
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Replace with your actual API credentials
$apiVersion = "100"; // Use the appropriate API version
$merchantId = "TESTE012345"; 
$password = "myapipassword3432489723"; 


$sessionId = isset($_POST['sessionId']) ? $_POST['sessionId'] : '';
$orderId = isset($_POST['orderId']) ? $_POST['orderId'] : '';

// Validate session ID and order ID
if (empty($sessionId) || !is_string($sessionId) || empty($orderId) || !is_string($orderId)) {
  http_response_code(400);
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Session ID and Order ID are required'));
  exit;
}

// Update the API URL
$apiUrl = "https://credimax.gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/$apiVersion/merchant/$merchantId/order/$orderId/transaction";

// Build the order payload
$orderPayload = array(
  'apiOperation' => 'PAY',
  'order' => array(
    'amount' => '10.00', // Replace with the actual amount
    'currency' => 'BHD',
    'description' => 'Purchase Description'
  ),
  'session' => array(
    'id' => $sessionId
  ),
  'sourceOfFunds' => array(
    'type' => 'CARD'
  )
);

// Convert payload to JSON
$orderPayloadJson = json_encode($orderPayload);

// Initialize cURL
$ch = curl_init($apiUrl);

// Set cURL options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "merchant.$merchantId:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Accept: application/json'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $orderPayloadJson);

// Make the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for cURL errors
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
  $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  http_response_code(500);
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode(array('error' => 'cURL Error: ' . $error_msg));
  exit;
}

// Close cURL
curl_close($ch);

// Decode the response
$orderResponse = json_decode($response, true);

// Check for JSON decode errors
if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
  http_response_code(500);
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode(array(
    'error' => 'Invalid JSON response',
    'details' => json_last_error_msg(),
    'raw_response' => $response
  ));
  exit;
}

// Handle the response accordingly
if (isset($orderResponse['result']) && $orderResponse['result'] == 'SUCCESS') {
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode(array(
    'status' => 'success',
    'message' => 'Payment successful!',
    'data' => $orderResponse
  ));
} else {
  http_response_code(400);
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode(array(
    'status' => 'error',
    'message' => 'Payment failed!',
    'data' => $orderResponse
  ));
}
?>

